# How to escape %s on the first string.format so it can be used in the second one?

Tags: java

I have a Java project in which I am working in our "query module". It is responsible for building queries from string we call "snippets".
To do that,
I am using things like this

```
myQueryOuter{
               %s
}

myInnerQuery{
      QUERY TEXT
}
```

Using String.Format will work, but now  one of my queries accepts values, which are coded as "%s", so an exception is thrown when I call the String.format method.

Is there anyway to escape the %s? That way I would create the whole query and then apply a String.Format to replace the %s for the values.

Or is there any nicer way to do something like this?

Thanks!

Edit:
Let me clarify:

I have the following

```
myQueryOuter{
                   %s
}
myInnerQuery{
          The next blank space should be filled by a parameter: %s
    }
```

I want to make

```
String output = String.Format(myOuterQuery, myInnerQuery) //this throws an exception
```

So I have this output

> myQueryOuter{
>           myInnerQuery{
>                 The next blank space should be filled by a parameter: %s
>           }
>       }

So I can call

```
String realOutput = String.format(output, "ThisIsMyParameter")
```

So I have

> myQueryOuter{
>           myInnerQuery{
>                 The next blank space should be filled by a parameter: this is my output
>           }
>       }

The exception is:

> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request
>   processing failed; nested exception is
>   java.util.MissingFormatArgumentException: Format specifier '%s'

Because I have  %s twice, but I want my output to HAVE the %s

Comment: This isn't clear.  What is the code that is throwing an exception?

Comment: Ouch, my eyes.  I though one %s was bad enough but nested format strings ....

Answer (score 3):

Before you format you need to replace % with %%

Then to format %%s with your parameter.. This will do the work

Hope that helps